# Update custom field in Salesforce when unsubscribed from external website

Tags: apex, visualforce, integration, connected-apps, custom-controller

I have a website where users can unsubcribe from our mailing list. While doing so, their email id will be carried in the URL like

> http://somerandomtestwebsite.com/unsubscribe/?email=test@test.com

Now, when they unsubscribe, a custom field on contact record which is called **unsubcribed_from_mailing_list** should be updated. This contact record will have the exact email id that is carried in the URL above.

Being new to Integration, I'm figuring out which is the right process of doing so. Can anyone please guide me the process of getting this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to make an API call from the unsubscribe example above, one solution would be to expose an Apex class as a REST web service. You can find Salesforce's documentation and code examples [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm)

I've also used webhooks to hit a REST web service from an application if thats available to you.

Another option would be to just use the Salesforce API to make the query and [update the contact record](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_update_fields.htm) as needed - again this assumes that you have the ability to do this from within your unsubscribe website.